# Using sizeof() on self-referential structs

Tags: c, struct

I have a global doubly linked list struct defined like this:

```
struct list {
     struct list *next;
     struct list *prev;
};
```

If I try to initialize a list of structures (in the same file) using `sizeof(struct list)`, I get `invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct list'`. Why would `struct list` be considered an incomplete type in this case? The struct just has 2 pointers whose size can be computed at compile-time.

Comment: Show us a complete verifiable code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, to get specific answer

Comment: This example code executes fine https://ideone.com/rvvgGI

Comment: Where is the structure type defined?  Is it outside any function at the top of the file?  Are there any headers involved?  Have you written `struct list;` inside the function where you're trying to initialize the structures?  Without the MCVE ([MCVE]), we're reduced to guessing, which is pointless because it really isn't possible to guess what you've done.  You need to show us the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also worth noting that the struct you've made is not a list, it's a node.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can only guess, but I'm guessing you don't include the header file where the structure is defined and only have a forward declaration.

That forward declaration only tells the compiler that the structure exists, but doesn't say anything about its members or the *size* of the structure. For that you need the full definition.